# How can I change file's last access?

Tags: linux, c++11, mktime

How can I change the file's last access by `utime` and `mktime` in linux ?
(for example, to update the file's last access to:
`11 (seconds) : 11 (minutes) : 11 (hour) : 11 (day) : 11 (month) : 1500 (year)`  )

I know that I can do it by `touch` command, but I try to do it by these system calls.. ideas?

Comment: Pick a programming language & share the code you're written so far.

Comment: programming language: c++11 @जलजनक

Answer (score 0):

you use utimensat  : [utimensat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html)

> utimensat() and futimens() update the timestamps of a file with
> nanosecond precision.  This contrasts with the historical
> utime(2) and utimes(2), which permit only second and microsecond
> precision, respectively, when setting file timestamps.

```
   With utimensat() the file is specified via the pathname given in
   pathname.  With futimens() the file whose timestamps are to be
   updated is specified via an open file descriptor, fd.

   For both calls, the new file timestamps are specified in the
   array times: times[0] specifies the new "last access time"
   (atime); times[1] specifies the new "last modification time"
   (mtime).  Each of the elements of times specifies a time as the
   number of seconds and nanoseconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01
   00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).  This information is conveyed in a
```